# Adding a toolbar button to Finder.app programmatically (macOS)

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, finder

I am looking for a way to add several toolbar buttons to Finder, which, when clicked, perform certain actions.
My research shows that injecting code into Finder process is impossible on latest versions of macOS due to SIP, yet this would be the most seamless way for the user.

There is a possibility to add a toolbar item by creating a Finder Sync extension. However there are 2 **problems**:

- There can be only one toolbar button per extension (I need several buttons)
- The toolbar button will have a dropdown arrow (see an image below). I do not need to show a menu, however, and therefore this arrow makes the button misleading. It must be a simple plain button that matches the current system theme and performs an action upon click.

So this is what I don't need (because of the drop down arrow):
[image: this is what I DO NOT NEED]

**Update:**
One of the ways to add a button, is drag and drop an .app bundle, holding Command key.

This approach has the following **problems**:

- This button wouldn't match the other toolbar buttons look&feel, as the icon for such button is taken from the .app bundle (so it wouldn't switch based on macOS light/dark theme, for example)
- It is impossible to add several toolbar buttons like that (as there needs to be one .app per 1 button). However, I need multiple buttons.

I am wondering if FinderSync allows creating "normal" (non menu) buttons

Is there a way to add a regular button to Finder's toolbar?

Comment: Do you need functionality different that just command-dragging an app onto the toolbar?

Comment: @red_menace the problem with command-dragging is that such button wouldn't match the native macOS look&feel: say a user switch Dark mode/Light mode. Now this button obviously won't change its background color as would other buttons. Another problem with this approach is that its hard to add a button programmatically and not break anything. And I would need to create a separate .app bundle for each button I want to add (I need to add several toolbar buttons that match current Theme (Dark/Light) ). Having said all that, I am wondering if FinderSync allows creating "normal" (non menu) buttons

Answer (score 0):

Please check out my Finder buttons:
https://github.com/lexrus/LTFinderButtons

Basically, I made every task a button app.

I'm trying Finder Sync Extension to do the same thing. All issues you found are true. Furthermore, there's problem #3:

You can not submit an app with Finder Sync Extension to the App Store.